# Terraform GCP create network fails. Error 400

Tags: networking, terraform-provider-gcp, infrastructure-as-code

This is a tricky question, because the Terraform plan fails, but the network was created. All this is very strange.

After a all long day trying  to solve, I'm quit. Only for the GCP team knowledge I document the problem here. If anybody knows the answer, please enlightenment me.

I'be working with Terrafom for more than 18 months and when I try something new is a nightmare find the solution. Now, this is the case. The plan executes wonderful with the GCP provider version 2.15, but in version 3 fails miserably in the cli with this error:

**Error: Error waiting to create Network: Error waiting for Creating Network: error while retrieving operation: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'project': 'projects/nvi-classdir-e954783d'. Must be a match of regex '(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}.)*(?:a-z?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:a-z0-9?))', invalid**

But in my GCP was created, AMAZING!!!

[Network was created always](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfsBw.png)

The problem was all the execution plan fails after because this error. My solution was simple, get back to 2.15 GCP provider. If somebody knows what happened here, please tell me.

My plan:

```
module "project" {
  source          = "../../modules/2021/gc-project"
  name            = "nvi-${var.sufix}"
  region          = "${var.region}"
  billing_account = "${var.billing_account}"
  org_id          = "${var.org_id}"
  # domain          = "${var.domain}"
}

module "network" {
  source                = "../../modules/2021/network"
  name                  = "${module.project.name}"
  project_id            = "${module.project.id}"
  region                = "${var.region}"
  zones                 = "${var.zones}"
  hosts_subnet_name     = "${var.subnet_id}"
  hosts_subnet_ip_range = "${var.hosts_subnet_ip_range}"
  net                   = "${var.net_name}"
  db_ext_access         = false # Disable external access to database
}
```

My network module:

```
resource "google_compute_network" "network" {
  name                    = "${var.net}-network"
  project                 = "${var.project_id}"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
}
```

The execution plan:

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  module.network.google_compute_network.network will be created
  + resource "google_compute_network" "network" {
      + auto_create_subnetworks         = false
      + delete_default_routes_on_create = false
      + gateway_ipv4                    = (known after apply)
      + id                              = (known after apply)
      + mtu                             = (known after apply)
      + name                            = "voz-e-imagen-network"
      + project                         = "projects/nvi-classdir-e954783d"
      + routing_mode                    = (known after apply)
      + self_link                       = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Comment: In my case, project that I want to attach was host project. And it was not discoverable. After moving it to related organization, it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be that `project.id` returns `project/[PROJECT_ID]`, while the API only expects the ID without `project` in front. Source: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/networks/insert

Good news is the `google_project` resource and data in Terraform also returns the project number. So replace `project.id` for `project.number` and it should work.